# By using Addthis, facebook sharer.php returns error 500 status for some users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share, addthis

I have Addthis in my HTTPS web page like this.

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style "> 
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a> 
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a> 
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a> 
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a> 
    <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a> 
</div> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

After login the facebook, when I click the facebook share button on my page, it always opens facebook sharer.php in a popup window but with error 500. If I copy the address of the popup into a new tab or refresh the popup, I can see the page without any issue.

This is only happened for most users, but not all of them. Some facebook accounts can see the proper content in the popup without any issue all time.

I know there is a message "Could not retrieve data from URL." in facebook debugger since some network policy.

I found this web site has the same issue too. https://myhealth.alberta.ca/

Does anyone happen to know why the 500 error is only happening on some facebook accounts, not alls?

Is there something wrong with https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?

Comment: I've looked into this as well and I think it's an issue on FB's side.  Since it only happens sometimes and because usually if you refresh, it starts working, I'm going to guess it's due to a bad end-point on FB's side that sometimes doesn't work and throws an error.

Comment: This is facebook issue. We do not see this error any more without any change on my side. Thanks.